# collection.aggregate(...).cursor is not a function loopback mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I have encountered **TypeError: collection.aggregate(...).cursor is not a function** in loopback v3.8.0, loopback mongodb connector v1.18.1.

```
var pipeline = [{
        $match: {
          restaurantId: id
        }
      }, {
        $project: {
          'y': {
            '$year': '$orderDateTime'
          },
          'm': {
            '$month': '$orderDateTime'
          },
          'd': {
            '$dayOfMonth': '$orderDateTime'
          }
        }
      }, {
        $group: {
          '_id': {
            'year': '$y',
            'month': '$m',
            'day': '$d'
          },
          'sum': {
            '$sum': '$totalAmount'
          }
        }
      }];

      Model.getDataSource().connector.connect(function(err, db) {
        var collection = db.collection('collection-name');
        collection.aggregate(pipeline).cursor({ batchSize: 2500, async: true }).exec();
      });
```

Instead of model name, I have also tried supplying collection name by following the below.

```
 var sampleCollection = SampleModel.getDataSource().connector.collection(SampleModel.modelName);
 var data = sampleCollection.aggregate(pipeline).cursor({ batchSize: 1000, async: true }).exec(function(err, cursor){
         console.log(cursor);
 });
```

Comment: I remember `aggregate` return an array, `cursor` is for normal operation (`find`)

Comment: @Khang But aggregate returns 'AggregationCursor' not an 'array'. I am doubtful whether this error has got anything to do with the driver itself. Please refer to https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2306

Answer (score 0):

```
var pipeline = [{
        $match: {
          restaurantId: ObjectID(id)
        }
      }, {
        $project: {
          'y': {
            '$year': '$orderDateTime'
          },
          'm': {
            '$month': '$orderDateTime'
          },
          'd': {
            '$dayOfMonth': '$orderDateTime'
          }
        }
      }, {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            year: '$y',
            month: '$m',
            day: '$d'
          },
          totalRevenue: {
            '$sum': '$totalBillAmount'
          }
        }
      }];
      Model.getDataSource().connector.connect(function(err, db) {
        var collection = db.collection('model-name');
        var cursor = collection.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, results) {
          console.log(results);
        });
      });
```

Comment: How i map the cursor results to an existing persisted model instance?